# linear algebra - my teacher said it's an important implication but I feel like he forgot to mention some details.

Tags: linear-algebra

what he exactly wrote on the board $\forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$: 
$$\forall X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \;\;\; X^{T}AY=0 \implies A= 0_{\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}$$

I feel like something is missing there yeah because if for example you take

$n=2$,$ X= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$, $A= \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & \pi \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ then for any vector $Y= \begin{bmatrix}
        y_1 \\
        y_2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

we have ($X^{T}AY=0) \land (A\neq0_{\mathbb{R^{2\times2}}}) $

which contradicts the implication above.

if anyone can tell me which information is required so the implication is true it would be great ! thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is correct. What he means is
$$(\forall X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \;\;\; X^{T}AY=0) \implies A= 0_{\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}$$
not
$$\forall X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \;\;\; (X^{T}AY=0 \implies A= 0_{\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}).$$

Comment: I see, parenthesis are crucial . thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A\ne0$. Set
$$
E_k=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\\1\rlap{\quad\gets k\text{-th row}}\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
If the coefficient at place $(i,j)$ of $A$ is nonzero, we have
$$
E_i^T A E_j\ne0
$$
so we can take $X=E_i$ and $Y=E_j$ for $X^TAY\ne0$.

In your example you are using a *fixed* $X$.